# Execute bash script Using FLASK+DOCKER

Tags: python, bash, docker, flask, swagger

I've been trying to create a FLASK api that executes simple shell scripts (e.g `session = Popen(['echo server_info.js" | node {}'.format(cmd)],shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE`). This worked very well but when i dockerized the application, the script stopped running and returned this error: b'/bin/sh: 1:  /path No such file or directory.
Also, I use swagger and blueprint for the FLASK. the dockerized version shows the swagger but does not update any change I make in the swagger.json file (the code:

```
SWAGGER_URL = '/swagger'
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'
SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        'app_name': "NAME"
    }
))
```

Also the docker file code:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/usr/src/app/app.py"]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: FYI you don't need to `mkdir` a `WORKDIR`: just specify it and it will be created if it doesn't exist. Also, it's more idiomatic to use `COPY . .` since you're already in the workdir (rather than to specify the full path).

Comment: Using `subprocess.Popen(shell=True)` is a very large security risk.  In your example if `cmd` includes any shell syntax it can run arbitrary commands.  Do you have a more complete example of the failing case; where does `cmd` come from and what value does it actually have?  Also note that the Docker image you show contains Python but not any other language runtime, and you won't have a `/usr/bin/node` inside the container.

Comment: What is the value of `cmd`?